# phantomJS signal connected to signal

Tags: qt, phantomjs

Going through the phantomJS code i ran into this in the webpage.cpp file (line 315)

```
connect(m_networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(resourceRequested(QVariant)),
            SIGNAL(resourceRequested(QVariant)));
```

And i don't quite understand how this works, i'm aware that you can connect signals to signals in Qt.
On the Qt documentation i found out that you can also connect signals directly to a method (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-2) , seeing that it's a 3 parameters call i thought that this would be the desired function on the webpage.cpp code, but connecting a signal to the same signal...i got completely lost there, any help?

PD: not very experienced in Qt i should say, sorry if it's a dumb question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three parameters QObject::connect()

```
connect(m_networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(resourceRequested(QVariant)),
        SIGNAL(resourceRequested(QVariant)));
```

is an equivalent of

```
connect(m_networkAccessManager, SIGNAL(resourceRequested(QVariant)),
        this, SIGNAL(resourceRequested(QVariant)));
```

Thus, `QNetworkAccessManager::resourceRequested(QVariant)` is connected to `WebPage::resourceRequested(QVariant)` and cause the latter to be emitted every time when the former is emitted.

More details in Qt [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#connect)